# Appending specified vector elements to all permutations of the vector, 'mostly random' row ordering for nearby integers etc

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, vector, permutation

In Matlab

1) If I have a vector, say [1 2 3] then I'm looking to create a matrix that contains every permutation of the vector, with another column appended containing, for each permutation, the first element of the original vector. I'd then like this matrix to be appended (by row) to another where the appended column is the second element. Then following this the same thing with the third. i.e.:

```
 3     2     1     1
 3     1     2     1
 2     3     1     1
 2     1     3     1
 1     2     3     1
 1     3     2     1
 3     2     1     2
 3     1     2     2
 2     3     1     2
 2     1     3     2
 1     2     3     2
 1     3     2     2
 3     2     1     3
 3     1     2     3
 2     3     1     3
 2     1     3     3
 1     2     3     3
 1     3     2     3
```

This is a long form way of writing it but I'm certain that someone here will be able to write it in a very concise way instead:

```
a = [1 2 3]; b = perms(a); 
c = [a(1); a(1); a(1); a(1); a(1); a(1)] ;
d = [a(2); a(2); a(2); a(2); a(2); a(2)] ;
e = [a(3); a(3); a(3); a(3); a(3); a(3)] ;
f = [ c; d; e ]
g = [ b; b ; b]
h = [g f]
```

2) Is there a way of doing a 'mostly random' ordering where, say you had a list such as:

```
64    69    72    72
64    72    69    75
76    67    72    70
62    69    65    72
71    74    65    77
74    69    65    72
67    71    74    74
67    76    72    79
76    79    71    82
60    64    69    67
64    67    72    70
67    64    60    67
72    65    69    68
74    71    65    74
65    69    62    72
71    74    67    77
71    62    65    65
67    72    64    75
77    74    71    77
76    72    67    75
77    69    74    72
74    67    71    70
79    71    74    74
76    71    79    74
69    62    65    65
65    62    71    65
69    65    74    68
69    64    60    67
71    79    74    82
71    74    77    77
69    74    77    77
72    69    77    72
77    72    69    75
74    65    71    68
71    62    67    65
71    77    74    80
74    77    71    80
77    71    74    74
69    65    72    68
65    71    74    74
67    71    76    74
64    67    60    70
65    72    69    75
71    74    79    77
72    76    69    79
67    62    71    65
72    69    65    72
69    72    76    75
79    74    71    77
72    67    64    70
71    67    76    70
67    72    76    75
71    65    74    68
65    69    60    72
69    72    77    75
64    69    60    72
76    69    72    72
69    76    72    79
64    72    67    75
72    77    69    80
67    76    71    79
69    60    65    63
67    60    64    63
71    64    67    67
69    60    64    63
71    67    62    70
60    64    67    67
74    69    77    72
65    74    71    77
62    71    65    74
67    71    64    74
65    74    69    77
76    67    71    70
62    67    71    70
74    71    79    74
77    74    69    77
67    64    71    67
62    65    71    68
65    60    69    63
62    65    69    68
60    69    65    72
71    65    62    68
65    69    74    72
67    74    71    77
71    79    76    82
69    74    65    77
69    77    72    80
67    71    62    74
72    64    67    67
74    77    69    80
76    72    69    75
69    72    65    75
71    76    79    79
64    60    67    63
64    60    69    63
74    65    69    68
79    76    71    79
64    67    71    70
72    67    76    70
72    76    67    79
69    65    60    68
60    67    64    70
69    64    72    67
69    65    62    68
65    62    69    65
74    71    67    74
65    69    72    72
72    69    64    72
60    69    64    72
76    71    67    74
64    71    67    74
60    65    69    68
74    79    71    82
65    71    62    74
67    64    72    67
71    67    74    70
79    71    76    74
62    71    67    74
74    71    77    74
71    67    64    70
72    64    69    67
71    76    67    79
69    77    74    80
77    69    72    72
69    72    64    75
72    69    76    72
```

you could order this so that the row order is random but that all of the numbers in the first column are mostly close to each other by a defined parameter (for example 62 might be followed by 67 or 58 but wouldn't be followed by say 80)? (To make things even more complicated might there be a way of specifying that this take place most but not all of the time?)

3) What's a concise way of creating a column vector that goes

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

etc, up until a specified length (or, failing that, up until a specified number)?

Comment: Can you explicit the 2)?

Comment: For 2): That's not enough input to solve this, but rejection sampling might be a solution.

Comment: You already have 2 answers for your Q1 and Q3 (_and you might get more_). I suggest you remove the Q2 from this post and post it separately, giving more explicit detail on the sorting rules. It's too vague as it is ...

Comment: Thank you @hoki - I'll almost certainly try that in a minute. Currently I've just updated the input so I'm wondering if that helps at all? I'm looking to order the rows by the numbers in the first column, I'm hoping for them to be randomised but so that they are always close to each other (as an example... 63 might be followed by 68 or 59 but not say 85... ?)

Answer (score 0):

For 1) You can use this code:

```
%sprows is just a utility function, which splits a matrix into a cell
sprows=@(x)(mat2cell(x,ones(size(x,1),1)))
%get all combinations of perms(a) and a
cell2mat(allcomb(sprows(perms(a)),sprows(a(:))))
```

It uses `allcomb` from matlab file exchange, available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb)

3):

```
x=repmat(0:3,4,1);
x=x(:);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you were told in the comments, your question 2 is not defined enough. It probably deserve a question on its own, with the constraints better detailed and explained.

---

That said, another alternative for 1) and 2):
*<sub>so many ways to do that</sub>*

### Q1:

long way

```
a = [1 2 3] ; %// starting set

n = numel(a) ;
lastCol = ones(factorial(n),1) * a ;
ap = [repmat(perms(a),n,1) lastCol(:)] ;
```

or directly without intermediate variable:

```
ap = [repmat(perms(a),numel(a),1) reshape(ones(factorial(numel(a)),1)*a,[],1)] ;
```

---

### Q3:

Same method than used above. A matrix multiplication reshaped into a colum vector:

```
n = 3       %// your specified number

v = 0:n ;
Vlong = reshape(ones(numel(v),1)*v,[],1) ;
```